# Использование split

Tags: java

Мне нужно, чтобы `value[1]` записывался в массив `name[i]`, а вместо этого вылезает ошибка в строчке

```
name[i] = value[1];
```

Помогите пожалуйста, не знаю как исправить. Все что можно перепробовал

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] surname = new String[capacity];
    String[] name = new String[capacity];
    String[] bd = new String[capacity];

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        bd[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {

        String[] value = bd[i].split(" ");
        surname[i] = value[0];
        name[i] = value[1];

    }
```

На вход заданы N строчек вида:

```
N      
Имя Фамилия 1 2 3 10
```

где 1 2 3 10 - это числа, записанные через пробел, и каждое из них находится в диапазоне от 0 до 10, а N это количество строчек.

Задача: необходимо запихнуть Имя и фамилию в отдельный массив типа String, а числа, соответсвующие имени и фамилии, в массив типа int, причем каждый элемент такого массива - это сумма этих чисел.

Answer (score 1):

Мои телепатические способности подсказывают, что код на самом деле выглядит как-то так:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int capacity = sc.nextInt(); // эту строку вы зачем-то выкинули из примера кода

String[] surname = new String[capacity];
String[] name = new String[capacity];
String[] bd = new String[capacity];

for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    bd[i] = sc.nextLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    String[] value = bd[i].split(" ");
    surname[i] = value[0];
    name[i] = value[1];
}
```

Тогда ошибка в том, что после чтения `sc.nextInt()` у вас остался не вычитан перевод строки, и он читается при следующем вызове `sc.nextLine()`, в результате чего в `bd[0]` попадает пустая строка и результат `bd[0].split(" ")` — это массив из одного пустого элемента. В результате `value[1]` выдаёт исключение.

Исправить это легко: добавьте дополнительный `sc.nextLine()`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int capacity = sc.nextInt();

sc.nextLine(); // добавить эту строку

String[] surname = new String[capacity];
String[] name = new String[capacity];
String[] bd = new String[capacity];

for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    bd[i] = sc.nextLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
    String[] value = bd[i].split(" ");
    surname[i] = value[0];
    name[i] = value[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что в ошибке то?
capacity объявлено?
Вы вкурсе вообще, что по логике работы у вас ввод должен происходить в строку 2 значения через пробелы?

Если вы вводите просто одно значение в строку, то возможна ошибка (Exception) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, которая говорит о том, что вы обращаетесь к массиву value и пытаетесь получить элементы массива, которые выходят из границ массива (используется индекс больше, чем число элементов массива).

Как вариант можно написать проверки вроде:

if(value.length>0) surname[i] = value[0];

if(value.length>1) name[i] = value[1];

Answer (score 0):

Напишите входные данные и какая именно ошибка.

```
        int capacity = 3;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] input = new String[capacity];
        String[] surname = new String[capacity];
        String[] name = new String[capacity];

        int[] result = new int[capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            input[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {

            String[] value = input[i].split(" ");
            surname[i] = value[0];
            name[i] = value[1];
            result[i] = (Integer.parseInt(value[2])+
                    Integer.parseInt(value[3])+
                    Integer.parseInt(value[4])+
                    Integer.parseInt(value[5]));
        }

        //результат
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
            System.out.println(name[i]+"  "+surname[i]+" -sum-> "+result[i]);
        }
```

я ввел такие строки

```
abc abc 1 2 3 4

bcd bcd 3 4 5 6

aaa aaa 1 1 1 1
```

на выходе получил

```
abc  abc -sum-> 10

bcd  bcd -sum-> 18

aaa  aaa -sum-> 4
```

Comment: Ошибка вида:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Homework.Split.main(Split.java:22)

Comment: @JetKey, у меня ошибки не было. Немного подправил код.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы первая строка задавала количество строк с именем и фамилией, т.е. например

2
Вася Петров 1 2 3 4
Петр Васильев 2 3 5 10

Если заменить

int capacity = 3;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int capacity = sc.nextInt();

Comment: @JetKey, дело в том, что sc.nextLine(); сразу переходит на следующую строку, и в нулевую ячейку массива записывается пустая строка, таким образом, получается что все элементы сдвигаются вправо на 1 ячейку.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. А как сделать, чтобы правильно все работало?

Comment: сделать массивы на 1 ячейку больше, и начинать обрабатывать не с нулевой ячейки, а с первой

Comment: Супер, все работает. Спасибо за помощь)